# Swap between two images with one click

Tags: javascript

I want to toggle betweeen two images of a bulb on and off with one click on that image using javascript. I tried with this code, but it doesn't works but I don't know why. Can you help me please?

```
<img id="bulb" onclick="changeImg()" src="off.gif">
<script>
function changeImg() {
    var imagen = document.getElementById('bulb');
    if (imagen.src = "on.gif") {
        imagen.src = "off.gif";
    } else {
        imagen.src = "on.gif";
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: = single equal means assignment and == means comparison so in your if statment you are using = not == so change it and hopefully your code will work

Comment: Missing == in your if statement. Must be (imagen.src == "on.gif")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your if condition to this:

```
if (imagen.src == "on.gif") {
    imagen.src = "off.gif";
} else {
    imagen.src = "on.gif";
}
```

You are using the [assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Assignment) operator instead of the [equality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Equality) operator.

Comment: `===` is preferred over `==` to avoid unexpected type conversion.

Comment: Exactly, you'll want to know when something is really wrong.

Comment: `==` will succeed silently. You already gave a good answer to the question, so I am not going to be an ass and give a slightly improved answer of my own in a quest for points. It seems you can't handle even the slightest criticism, but your name already gave that away.

Comment: @BasDirks yeah it will succeed with a number or an object that is equal to `"on.gif"`.

Comment: The point is that now it is "on.gif", but it could become something else when this is wrapper up in a function. This isn't about how likely things can go wrong, but rather about minimizing the extend to which things can go wrong. These things add up.

Comment: @BasDirks when this time comes and the code grows up, if necessary, of course `===` could be useful. But is not the case right now. It would mess things to the user who's already confused with such a simple problem.

Comment: I understand your point of view, but `===` is faster and more secure, so teaching this as a best practice can't hurt. My initial comment wasn't meant to challenge your solution, but merely to optimize it.

Comment: @OscarHermida you'll need to give us a few more details on this. What is happening, errors in the console, browser, whatever. Update your question with new status.

Comment: What is happening is that the image only swaps on first click. After that nothing happens.

Comment: @OscarHermida are you sure that the image names(mainly at the condition) are correct? Try this condition: `imagen.src.indexOf("on.gif") > -1`.

Comment: The image names are correct. Regarding to the condition, imagen.src.indexOf("on.gif") > -1 throws true. imagen.src.indexOf("off.gif") > -1 throws false.

Comment: @OscarHermida well, actually I can't help you any further on this with this lack of information. I suggest you create a jsfiddle.com with your code or something else.